# slickGoTo doesn't change active slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-slick

I added slider using `react-slick` to my React app. For `<Slider>` I added ref, and I'm trying use it to change active slide:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';

const TestSlider = () => {
  const handleOnClick = index => {
    sliderRef.slick('slickGoTo', index);
    // also try sliderRef.slickGoTo(index);
  };

  <Slider {...settings} ref={sliderRef}>
    ...
  </Slider>
}
```

but I got an error:

> TypeError: sliderRef.slick is not a function

Why doesn't this work for me?

> "react": "^16.6.3",
>
> "react-slick": "^0.27.12",

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to react-slick's [slickGoTo() documentation](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/slick-go-to), you need to pass a function as the ref. Something like:

```js
  const handleOnClick = index => {
    this.slider.slickGoTo(index);
  };

  <Slider {...settings} ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}>
    ...
  </Slider>
```

If you want to create a ref using the `useRef` hook, it would look like:

```js
  const sliderRef = useRef();

  const handleOnClick = index => {
    sliderRef.current.slickGoTo(index);
  };

  <Slider {...settings} ref={sliderRef}>
    ...
  </Slider>
```

Comment: const sliderRef = useRef(); → const sliderRef = useRef(null);